# Is this bijection between subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ right?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I was trying to prove the following: For some fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define the following set of integers $S_4(n) = \{k \in \mathbb{Z} : k = n+j, j \in \{0,1,2,3\}\subset \mathbb{Z}\}$, then if $A = \{0,1,2,3\}\subset \mathbb{Z}$, the function $f : S_4(n) \to A$ which sends each number to the remainder of the division by $4$ is a bijection.

My proof was the following: write $n = 4q + r$ where $q$ is the quotient of the division by $4$ and $r$ is the remainder. Then, $S_4(n) = \{n_k \in \mathbb{Z} : n_k = 4q+(r+k), k \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}\subset \mathbb{Z}\}$. First we prove injectivity. For some $n_i, n_j \in S_4(n)$  consider $f(n_i) = f(n_j)$. But $n_i = 4q+(r+i)$ and $n_j = 4q + (r+j)$, and so $f(n_i) = r+ i$ and $f(n_j) = r+j$ and in that case we have $i = j$ implying that $n_i = n_j$ and thus $f$ is injective.

To prove surjectivity we do as follows: given $a \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ we want $n_k = 4q+(r+k)$ such that $f(n_k) = a$. But this means $r+k = a$ and so we simply take $k = a - r$ which is the same as taking $n_{a -r}$, so that we have $f(n_{a-r}) = r+(a-r)=a$ as desired, so that $f$ is surjective.

Is this proof correct? I think there's just a problem. First, I didn't prove that if $r$ is the remainder of $n$ by $4$ then $r+1$ is the remainder of $n+1$ by $4$. Second, I didn't prove that $a - r \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ which is necessary so that $n_{a-r} \in S_n(4)$. Are those real problems with this proof? Are any other errors there? If some, how can I make this better?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Well, how many elements are there in $S_4(n)$? Therefore you only need either injectivity or surjectvity (not both)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M Turgeon already pointed out some flaws in your proof. He also mentioned, that it is sufficient to prove injectivity. So let me give you a short argument, why injectivity holds:

Let $a,b\in S_4(n)=\{n,n+1,n+2,n+3\}$. Certainly $|a-b|<4$. We can write,  $a=4q_1+r_1$ and $b=4q_2+r_2$, such that $0\leq r_1,r_2<4$.

Now, assume $f(a)=f(b)$, but $a\neq b$. Then first condition yields $r_1=r_2$ and the second $q_1\neq q_2$, so
$$|a-b|=\left|(4q_1+r_1)-(4q_2+r_2)\right|=\left|4(q_1-q_2)+(r_1-r_2)\right|=4\left|q_1-q_2\right|\geq 4\cdot 1 =4$$
which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of injectivity is not quite complete (as Tomas mentionned): you have to consider the case where $r+i\geq 4$, in which case $f(n_i)=(r+i)-4\neq r+i$ (also, for your redefinition of $S_4(n)$, you don't want $k=4$). Once this is fixed, since there are $4$ elements in $S_4(n)$, injectivity is enough to get bijectivity.

Your proof of surjectivity has indeed one little flaw, i.e. you want $a-r\in\{0,1,2,3\}$. But all you need is a case-by-case analysis: if $a-r$ is not what you want, just add $4$. The second problem you mention is not needed.

In fact, using modular arithmetic (instead of explicitly writing $n=4q+r$) should simplify greatly the argument.

Comment: I disagree. In the proof of injectivy, the OP assumes, that $f(4q+r+i)=r+i$. This does not hold in general, since it might happen that $r+i\geq 4$.

Comment: @Tomas You're right, I missed that

Comment: @MTurgeon, thanks for your help! Indeed I thought on that problem when proving injectivity. I'll try to do it again. Indeed I've never studied modular arithmetic and that's why I didn't use it. Could you point me to somewhere I can read about it? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @user1620696 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic